# Can anyone suggest an alternative to select drop-down box with JQuery Mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, appmobi

I've built a JQuery Mobile based app, wrapped in AppMobi, released for both iOS and Android. To date I've heard of no major issues. Today I heard that a user with Android ICS is having repeatable crashes when accessing any drop down select boxes - I cannot reproduce the problem with my older test unit. I've had them try my raw html site as well - which does not yield the same behaviour, but the AppMobi guys seem to take a dim view on the use of JQuery Mobile so dont anticipate much help from that quarter.

My main alternative is likely going to be replacing the standard select drop down select boxes with some alternative.

Can anyone suggest an alternative (the simpler the better) that will yield the same functionality as the below code?

```
<select id="punits">
    <option value="in_H2O">in H2O</option>
    <option value="in_HG">in Hg</option>
    <option value="psi">psi</option>
    <option value="cm_H2O">cm H2O</option>
    <option value="cm_HG">cm Hg</option>
    <option value="kPa">kPa</option>
  </select>
```

Thanking you in advance

Comment: Is writing a custom jQuery plugin an option? i think it will take just a few minutes to create one that does work like a dropdownlist, but uses <div>'s or <li>'s instead for example.

Comment: Quite possibly, but I lack the skills to know even how to start going about that

Comment: I would try the solution of Hessius in the first place, creating a custom one like i did below is much more work. Please let us know how you solved it, that might help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate both of your efforts, and yes I agree with you Michael. Have created a custom build for this user using Hessius's suggestion and will post his feedback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order of the simpler the better - Here's a one line fix:
Might I suggest using the jQuery Mobile built in custom select menu? 
Documentation @ http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/selectmenu-custom

Basically use the same html but add this line to your mobileinit

```
$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.nativeMenu = false;
```

This will yield all select menus being rendered by jQuery Mobile instead of the native controls

Comment: Thanks - that was a solution. User has reported back that it has stopped the crashes, although it makes loading much slower.

Comment: Great! When jQM 1.2 lands you cold opt to use vertically grouped radio buttons in a [popup](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html) which would likely improve performance

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick and dirty example, it has no styling at this point, but something like this could work.

JsFiddle running example: http://jsfiddle.net/29vBZ/3/

You could replace the show() and hide() with slideDown() and slideUp() accordingly to create some kind of eyecandy, like i did here: http://jsfiddle.net/29vBZ/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="customSelect"> 
    <div id="customSelectCaption"></div>
    <div class="customSelectItem" identifier="in_H2O">in H2O</div> 
    <div class="customSelectItem" identifier="in_HG">in Hg</div> 
    <div class="customSelectItem" identifier="psi">psi</div> 
    <div class="customSelectItem" identifier="cm_H2O">cm H2O</div> 
    <div class="customSelectItem" identifier="cm_HG">cm Hg</div> 
    <div class="customSelectItem" identifier="kPa">kPa</div> 
</div>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//hide the options on load
$('#customSelect').children('.customSelectItem').hide();

//give it the caption of the first option as default.
var firstChild = $('#customSelect .customSelectItem');
$('#customSelect').attr('identifier', firstChild.attr('identifier'));
$('#customSelectCaption').html(firstChild.html());

//set a variable so we know in which state it is.
$('#customSelect').data('customSelectState', false);

//bind the click event so you can take action on click.
$('#customSelect').click(function(event){
    if($('#customSelect').data('customSelectState') == false)
    {
        //hide the caption, show the items.
        $('#customSelectCaption').hide();
        $('.customSelectItem').show();

        //set the variable so we know the state is now 'open'.
        $('#customSelect').data('customSelectState', true);
    }
    else
    {
        //set the new identifier.
        $('#customSelect').attr('identifier', $(event.target).attr('identifier'));

        //set the new caption.
        var newCaption = $(event.target).html();
        $('#customSelectCaption').html(newCaption);

        //show the caption, hide the items.
        $('#customSelectCaption').show();
        $('.customSelectItem').hide();

        //set the variable so we know the state is now 'closed'.
        $('#customSelect').data('customSelectState', false);
    }
});
});
```

To retreive the current value, you could simply do:

```
var currentSelection = $('#customSelect').attr('identifier');
```

Ofcource this only works for only one "fake" dropdown list, but could be expanded to a full jQuery plugin which does the same for multiple. I hope this is helping you in some way.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the effort. Will keep in mind if the performance hit that comes with rendering with JQuery becomes too much for users to bear

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the new (1.2) JQuery Mobile popup feature (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/), with stacked radio buttons. A bit more complex than a simple drop down select menu, but works just fine on both IOS and Android